# AngularJS + Colorbox

Tags: jquery, angularjs, colorbox

I'm using Colorbox inside an AngularJS app to easily load an external html onto the  page (via Ajax in a lightbox). Problem is, it looks like the lightbox is not recognizing AngularJS. To test this, I was trying to load a $scope variable onto the lightbox. And it's not seeing it.

Any idea how to make Colorbox work inside AngularJS?

Comment: Is this possible? I am under the impression that colorbox loads an iframe - thus its an entirely different html document.

Comment: There is a separate option to load an iframe instead. So I'm assuming the default is load an ajax page.

Comment: Me too facing this problem